# api gateway for spring boot microservices in open shift

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a microservices based application running in openshift for which we need to design  an API gateway.

This API gateway is expected to perform minimal checks like authentication , routing to appropriate micro services , logging , tracing etc ( Authorisation would be handled by respective micro services )

Should we go for a commercial product ( nginx , Red Hat OpenShift API gateway)  or an open source  spring cloud gateway would suffice ?

Please note these APIs are not exposed to external  world and does not need all features of a full fledged API gateway like developer portal ,usage limits by consumer etc.

Comment: Check [this](https://engineering.opsgenie.com/comparing-api-gateway-performances-nginx-vs-zuul-vs-spring-cloud-gateway-vs-linkerd-b2cc59c65369)

Answer (score 1):

> Should we go for a commercial product ( nginx , Red Hat OpenShift API
> gateway) or an open source spring cloud gateway would suffice ?

Open-source version of Kong will work also.

i would suggest to check & read this article first : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/api-gateway-identity-server-comparison-ec439468cc8a

[image]

You can check for the Kong API gateway once, as it supports authentication &  authorization with API key along with options like OIDC, JWT, and many plugin supports.

As you don't require a developer portal otherwise there is a good option [Konga](https://github.com/pantsel/konga).

Kong is very lightweight and in the background runs on the **Nginx** platform has verities of the plugin supports also and good community support.

There is also a plugin for logging & monitoring you can attach or enable them use them and Kong will forward the data to the central log system.

People also use Kong at edge & service mesh internally for **mtls** and networking if required.

we been using Kong for a long and have written some good articles on Kong & keycloak also if you are using Keycloak IAM. : https://faun.pub/securing-the-application-with-kong-keycloak-101-e25e0ae9ec56

You can also check out basic setup of Kong & Konga : https://faun.pub/kong-api-gateway-with-konga-dashboard-ae95b6d1fec7

Kong installation : https://docs.konghq.com/enterprise/2.5.x/deployment/installation/docker/

There is also another API gateway called : https://wso2.com/api-manager/

Answer (score 0):

I use **kong api gateway** for all the environments including **production** and routing to the ***spring boot microservices***. I use ***Istio service mesh*** for **api authorization** which can also be achieved with the microservices as well.

Kong serves hundreds of request per second in our production environment.

It provides all the features you are looking for and its open source and license based.

https://konghq.com/install/

You can also try ambassador https://www.getambassador.io/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on OpenShift, the RedHat OpenShift has a solution called OpenShift API Management. This supports most of your needs.

Checkout https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift/openshift-api-management